# adding new line in exported csv file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

i exporting data into csv file by using poi library in java.

im facing a problem, \n in my javacode is not taking in the csv file .it gives entire list of data in one line,

Also how can i give space from my java.

Answer (score 2):

Some editors like notepad expect MS-DOS new lines which are \r\n and will treat files with just \n as being entirely on one line.

However most editors incl excel will accept the UNIX style \n.  You can use the System.getProperty("line.seperator") or the %n in printf to use the platform local newline.